# openai.Moderation not working (openai version issue)

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api

As I'm trying to test my chatbot based on OpenAI API, I'm getting the following error on the Terminal :

'You tried to access openai.Moderation, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python
for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`'

The code is as follow :

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

# load values from the .env file if it exists
load_dotenv()

# configure OpenAI
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

INSTRUCTIONS = """You are an AI assistant that is an expert in alcoholic beverages.
You know about cocktails, wines, spirits and beers.
You can provide advice on drink menus, cocktail ingredients, how to make cocktails, and anything else related to alcoholic drinks.
If you are unable to provide an answer to a question, please respond with the phrase "I'm just a simple barman, I can't help with that."
Please aim to be as helpful, creative, and friendly as possible in all of your responses.
Do not use any external URLs in your answers. Do not refer to any blogs in your answers.
Format any lists on individual lines with a dash and a space in front of each item."""
ANSWER_SEQUENCE = "\nAI:"
QUESTION_SEQUENCE = "\nHUMAN:"
TEMPERATURE = 0.5
MAX_TOKENS = 500
FREQUENCY_PENALTY = 0
PRESENCE_PENALTY = 0.6
# limits how many questions we include in the prompt
MAX_CONTEXT_QUESTIONS = 10


def get_response(instructions, previous_questions_and_answers, new_question):
    """Get a response from ChatCompletion

    Args:
        instructions: The instructions for the chat bot - this determines how it will behave
        previous_questions_and_answers: Chat history
        new_question: The new question to ask the bot

    Returns:
        The response text
    """
    # build the messages
    messages = [
        { "role": "system", "content": instructions },
    ]
    # add the previous questions and answers
    for question, answer in previous_questions_and_answers[-MAX_CONTEXT_QUESTIONS:]:
        messages.append({ "role": "user", "content": question })
        messages.append({ "role": "assistant", "content": answer })
    # add the new question
    messages.append({ "role": "user", "content": new_question })

    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        temperature=TEMPERATURE,
        max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=FREQUENCY_PENALTY,
        presence_penalty=PRESENCE_PENALTY,
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message.content


def get_moderation(question):
    """
    Check the question is safe to ask the model

    Parameters:
        question (str): The question to check

    Returns a list of errors if the question is not safe, otherwise returns None
    """

    errors = {
        "hate": "Content that expresses, incites, or promotes hate based on race, gender, ethnicity, religion, nationality, sexual orientation, disability status, or caste.",
        "hate/threatening": "Hateful content that also includes violence or serious harm towards the targeted group.",
        "self-harm": "Content that promotes, encourages, or depicts acts of self-harm, such as suicide, cutting, and eating disorders.",
        "sexual": "Content meant to arouse sexual excitement, such as the description of sexual activity, or that promotes sexual services (excluding sex education and wellness).",
        "sexual/minors": "Sexual content that includes an individual who is under 18 years old.",
        "violence": "Content that promotes or glorifies violence or celebrates the suffering or humiliation of others.",
        "violence/graphic": "Violent content that depicts death, violence, or serious physical injury in extreme graphic detail.",
    }
    response = openai.Moderation.create(input=question)
    if response.results[0].flagged:
        # get the categories that are flagged and generate a message
        result = [
            error
            for category, error in errors.items()
            if response.results[0].categories[category]
        ]
        return result
    return None


def main():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    # keep track of previous questions and answers
    previous_questions_and_answers = []
    while True:
        # ask the user for their question
        new_question = input(
            Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + "What can I get you?: " + Style.RESET_ALL
        )
        # check the question is safe
        errors = get_moderation(new_question)
        if errors:
            print(
                Fore.RED
                + Style.BRIGHT
                + "Sorry, you're question didn't pass the moderation check:"
            )
            for error in errors:
                print(error)
            print(Style.RESET_ALL)
            continue
        response = get_response(INSTRUCTIONS, previous_questions_and_answers, new_question)

        # add the new question and answer to the list of previous questions and answers
        previous_questions_and_answers.append((new_question, response))

        # print the response
        print(Fore.CYAN + Style.BRIGHT + "Here you go: " + Style.NORMAL + response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've managed to create a virtual environment, but the moment I write whatsoever to the bot, I get the error related to openai.Moderation I've tried the "openai migrate", but apparently it's not supported in Windows, and I've also tried `pip install openai==0.28`but it doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize if I missed some crucial information or badly presented my issue, I'm still very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a hard refactor has been performed to the library. Looking an issue on github (https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742) seems that the Moderation dir changed, among others:

```
openai.Moderation.create() -> client.moderations.create()
```

So, I suggest you to try the devs recommendation, with the following functions:

```
from openai import OpenAI

# create a client
client = OpenAI(
  api_key=os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'],  # this is also the default, it can be omitted
)

def get_response(instructions, previous_questions_and_answers, new_question):
    """Get a response from ChatCompletion

    Args:
        instructions: The instructions for the chat bot - this determines how it will behave
        previous_questions_and_answers: Chat history
        new_question: The new question to ask the bot

    Returns:
        The response text
    """
    # build the messages
    messages = [
        { "role": "system", "content": instructions },
    ]
    # add the previous questions and answers
    for question, answer in previous_questions_and_answers[-MAX_CONTEXT_QUESTIONS:]:
        messages.append({ "role": "user", "content": question })
        messages.append({ "role": "assistant", "content": answer })
    # add the new question
    messages.append({ "role": "user", "content": new_question })
    
    # UPDATED LIBRARY
    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        temperature=TEMPERATURE,
        max_tokens=MAX_TOKENS,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=FREQUENCY_PENALTY,
        presence_penalty=PRESENCE_PENALTY,
    )
    return completion.choices[0].message.content

def get_moderation(question):
    """
    Check the question is safe to ask the model

    Parameters:
        question (str): The question to check

    Returns a list of errors if the question is not safe, otherwise returns None
    """

    errors = {
        "hate": "Content that expresses, incites, or promotes hate based on race, gender, ethnicity, religion, nationality, sexual orientation, disability status, or caste.",
        "hate/threatening": "Hateful content that also includes violence or serious harm towards the targeted group.",
        "self-harm": "Content that promotes, encourages, or depicts acts of self-harm, such as suicide, cutting, and eating disorders.",
        "sexual": "Content meant to arouse sexual excitement, such as the description of sexual activity, or that promotes sexual services (excluding sex education and wellness).",
        "sexual/minors": "Sexual content that includes an individual who is under 18 years old.",
        "violence": "Content that promotes or glorifies violence or celebrates the suffering or humiliation of others.",
        "violence/graphic": "Violent content that depicts death, violence, or serious physical injury in extreme graphic detail.",
    }
    # UPDATED LIBRARY
    response = client.chat.completions.create(input=question)
    if response.results[0].flagged:
        # get the categories that are flagged and generate a message
        result = [
            error
            for category, error in errors.items()
            if response.results[0].categories[category]
        ]
        return result
    return None
```

EDIT:

I also suggest to review the announcement to review if you need further changes to the code or imports.